# Gulp compiled SASS output inconsistent

Tags: sass, gulp

I'm working on a project with a team. When I compile the SASS using `gulp watch`, the generated CSS files begin with this:

`/*! typey | GPLv2 License | https://github.com/jptaranto/typey */`

and they end with something like this:

`/*# sourceMappingURL=assessment-analysis.css.map */`

When my other team members compile, those lines are not output. This means that whenever I work on the SASS after one of them (or vice versa), the entire commit is polluted with hundreds of CSS files that are changed only by adding or deleting these comments. Not sure why gulp would have different output for the same project... how can I get it to stop?

EDIT: Here are the contents of my `gulpfile.js`. This is also in version control, so all of us are using the exact same settings:

```
/* eslint-env node, es6 */
/* global Promise */
/* eslint-disable key-spacing, one-var, no-multi-spaces, max-nested-callbacks, quote-props */

'use strict';

var importOnce = require('node-sass-import-once'),
  path = require('path');

var options = {};

// #############################
// Edit these paths and options.
// #############################

// The root paths are used to construct all the other paths in this
// configuration. The "project" root path is where this gulpfile.js is located.
// While Zen distributes this in the theme root folder, you can also put this
// (and the package.json) in your project's root folder and edit the paths
// accordingly.
options.rootPath = {
  project     : __dirname + '/',
  styleGuide  : __dirname + '/styleguide/',
  theme       : __dirname + '/'
};

options.theme = {
  name       : 'mywebsite',
  root       : options.rootPath.theme,
  components : options.rootPath.theme + 'components/',
  build      : options.rootPath.theme + 'components/asset-builds/',
  css        : options.rootPath.theme + 'components/asset-builds/css/',
  js         : options.rootPath.theme + 'js/'
};

// Set the URL used to access the Drupal website under development. This will
// allow Browser Sync to serve the website and update CSS changes on the fly.
options.drupalURL = '';
options.drupalURL = 'http://dev.mywebsite-local.com';

// Define the node-sass configuration. The includePaths is critical!
options.sass = {
  importer: importOnce,
  includePaths: [
    options.theme.components,
    options.rootPath.project + 'node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets',
    options.rootPath.project + 'node_modules/chroma-sass/sass',
    options.rootPath.project + 'node_modules/support-for/sass',
    options.rootPath.project + 'node_modules/typey/stylesheets',
    options.rootPath.project + 'node_modules/zen-grids/sass'
  ],
  outputStyle: 'expanded'
};

// Define which browsers to add vendor prefixes for.
options.autoprefixer = {
  browsers: [
    '> 1%',
    'ie 9'
  ]
};

// Define the style guide paths and options.
options.styleGuide = {
  source: [
    options.theme.components
  ],
  mask: /\.less|\.sass|\.scss|\.styl|\.stylus/,
  destination: options.rootPath.styleGuide,

  builder: 'builder/twig',
  namespace: options.theme.name + ':' + options.theme.components,
  'extend-drupal8': true,

  // The css and js paths are URLs, like '/misc/jquery.js'.
  // The following paths are relative to the generated style guide.
  css: [
    // base/special stylesheets
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'base.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'layouts.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'chroma-kss-styles.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'kss-only.css'),
    // component stylesheets
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'box.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'clearfix.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'comment.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'footer.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'header.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'hidden.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'highlight-mark.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'inline-links.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'inline-sibling.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'messages.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'print-none.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'responsive-video.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'visually-hidden.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'watermark.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'wireframe.css'),
    // form stylesheets
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'autocomplete.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'collapsible-fieldset.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'form-item.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'form-table.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'progress-bar.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'progress-throbber.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'resizable-textarea.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'table-drag.css'),
    // navigation stylesheets
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'breadcrumb.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'more-link.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'nav-menu.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'navbar.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'pager.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'skip-link.css'),
    path.relative(options.rootPath.styleGuide, options.theme.css + 'tabs.css')
  ],
  js: [
  ],

  homepage: 'homepage.md',
  title: 'mywebsite Style Guide'
};

// Define the paths to the JS files to lint.
options.eslint = {
  files  : [
    options.rootPath.project + 'gulpfile.js',
    options.theme.js + '**/*.js',
    '!' + options.theme.js + '**/*.min.js',
    options.theme.components + '**/*.js',
    '!' + options.theme.build + '**/*.js'
  ]
};

// If your files are on a network share, you may want to turn on polling for
// Gulp watch. Since polling is less efficient, we disable polling by default.
options.gulpWatchOptions = {};
// options.gulpWatchOptions = {interval: 1000, mode: 'poll'};


// ################################
// Load Gulp and tools we will use.
// ################################
var gulp      = require('gulp'),
  $           = require('gulp-load-plugins')(),
  browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
  del         = require('del'),
  // gulp-load-plugins will report "undefined" error unless you load gulp-sass manually.
  sass        = require('gulp-sass'),
  kss         = require('kss'),
  cache       = require('gulp-cached');

// The default task.
gulp.task('default', ['build']);

// #################
// Build everything.
// #################
gulp.task('build', ['styles:production', 'styleguide', 'lint']);

// ##########
// Build CSS.
// ##########
var sassFiles = [
  options.theme.components + '**/*.scss',
  // Do not open Sass partials as they will be included as needed.
  '!' + options.theme.components + '**/_*.scss',
  // Chroma markup has its own gulp task.
  '!' + options.theme.components + 'style-guide/kss-example-chroma.scss'
];

gulp.task('styles', function () {
  return gulp.src(sassFiles)
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(cache())
    .pipe(sass(options.sass).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer(options.autoprefixer))
    .pipe($.rename({dirname: ''}))
    .pipe($.size({showFiles: true}))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(options.theme.css))
    .pipe($.if(browserSync.active, browserSync.stream({match: '**/*.css'})));
});

gulp.task('styles:production', ['clean:css'], function () {
  return gulp.src(sassFiles)
    .pipe(sass(options.sass).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer(options.autoprefixer))
    .pipe($.rename({dirname: ''}))
    .pipe($.size({showFiles: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(options.theme.css));
});

// ##################
// Build style guide.
// ##################
gulp.task('styleguide', ['clean:styleguide', 'styleguide:kss-example-chroma'], function () {
  return kss(options.styleGuide);
});

gulp.task('styleguide:kss-example-chroma', function () {
  return gulp.src(options.theme.components + 'style-guide/kss-example-chroma.scss')
    .pipe(sass(options.sass).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe($.replace(/(\/\*|\*\/)\n/g, ''))
    .pipe($.rename('kss-example-chroma.twig'))
    .pipe($.size({showFiles: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(options.theme.build + 'twig'));
});

// Debug the generation of the style guide with the --verbose flag.
gulp.task('styleguide:debug', ['clean:styleguide', 'styleguide:kss-example-chroma'], function () {
  options.styleGuide.verbose = true;
  return kss(options.styleGuide);
});

// #########################
// Lint Sass and JavaScript.
// #########################
gulp.task('lint', ['lint:sass', 'lint:js']);

// Lint JavaScript.
gulp.task('lint:js', function () {
  return gulp.src(options.eslint.files)
    .pipe($.eslint())
    .pipe($.eslint.format());
});

// Lint JavaScript and throw an error for a CI to catch.
gulp.task('lint:js-with-fail', function () {
  return gulp.src(options.eslint.files)
    .pipe($.eslint())
    .pipe($.eslint.format())
    .pipe($.eslint.failOnError());
});

// Lint Sass.
gulp.task('lint:sass', function () {
  return gulp.src(options.theme.components + '**/*.scss')
    .pipe($.sassLint())
    .pipe($.sassLint.format());
});

// Lint Sass and throw an error for a CI to catch.
gulp.task('lint:sass-with-fail', function () {
  return gulp.src(options.theme.components + '**/*.scss')
    .pipe($.sassLint())
    .pipe($.sassLint.format())
    .pipe($.sassLint.failOnError());
});

// ##############################
// Watch for changes and rebuild.
// ##############################
gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'watch:lint-and-styleguide', 'watch:js']);

gulp.task('browser-sync', ['watch:css'], function () {
  if (!options.drupalURL) {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
  return browserSync.init({
    proxy: options.drupalURL,
    noOpen: false
  });
});

gulp.task('watch:css', ['clean:css', 'styles'], function () {
  return gulp.watch(options.theme.components + '**/*.scss', options.gulpWatchOptions, ['styles']);
});

gulp.task('watch:lint-and-styleguide', ['styleguide', 'lint:sass'], function () {
  return gulp.watch([
    options.theme.components + '**/*.scss',
    options.theme.components + '**/*.twig'
  ], options.gulpWatchOptions, ['styleguide', 'lint:sass']);
});

gulp.task('watch:js', ['lint:js'], function () {
  return gulp.watch(options.eslint.files, options.gulpWatchOptions, ['lint:js']);
});

// ######################
// Clean all directories.
// ######################
gulp.task('clean', ['clean:css', 'clean:styleguide']);

// Clean style guide files.
gulp.task('clean:styleguide', function () {
  // You can use multiple globbing patterns as you would with `gulp.src`
  return del([
    options.styleGuide.destination + '*.html',
    options.styleGuide.destination + 'kss-assets',
    options.theme.build + 'twig/*.twig'
  ], {force: true});
});

// Clean CSS files.
gulp.task('clean:css', function () {
  return del([
    options.theme.css + '**/*.css',
    options.theme.css + '**/*.map'
  ], {force: true});
});


// Resources used to create this gulpfile.js:
// - https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit/blob/master/gulpfile.babel.js
// - https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/blob/master/README.md
// - http://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/
```

Comment: Are you stripping CSS comments? By passing a flag or something like that?

Comment: Passing a flag where? Into the gulp watch command?

Comment: You need to share your code. It might happen that they are running the gulp in prod mode where the files are minified and comments are stripped whereas you might be running in dev mode where the files are not minified and comments stay as is..

Comment: What code do I need to share? I don't know much about gulp.

Comment: Gulp code? ....

Comment: Shared my gulpfile.js.